# Toolbar and treeview Icons missing when displaying CHM file using HH API

Tags: chm, html-help

Just encountered an interesting problem. I have a CHM file. If I display it using Process.Start it displays correctly.

If however I launch it using the HH API it displays without any icons in the toolbar and treeview; the main content, including graphics, displays correctly. Here's what it looks like - with a few article titles scribbled out: [alt text http://img527.imageshack.us/img527/3430/problemhelpfilehl2.png](http://img527.imageshack.us/img527/3430/problemhelpfilehl2.png)

The same file works fine on a colleagues machine with the same setup.

Any thoughts as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that I was giving HH API a relative path to the help file. Now that I'm using an absolute path the problem seems to have gone away.